# Calcular la suma de los elementos de las columnas y la diagonal en una matriz 4x4. en lenguaje C

Tags: c

Hola he estado intentado sumar las columnas y las diagonales en mi programa el cual genera una matriz 4x4 al introducir 16 dígitos he logrado generar la matriz pero no he podido ser capaz de hacer la suma de las columnas una por una y de las diagonales en el lenguaje C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
int matriz[10][10], col=4 , reng=4, i=0, j=0;
 for(i = 0;i < reng;i++)
 {
 for(j = 0;j < col;j++){ // Se introducen los digito para hacer la matriz
 printf("ESCRIBE LOS VALORES [%d][%d]==>\t", i+1, j+1);
 scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
 }
 }
 printf("\n\n\t\t MATRIZ:"); // Se imprime la matriz original
 printf("\n\n");
 for(i = 0;i < reng;i++){
 printf("\n\t\t");
 for(j = 0;j < col;j++){
 printf(" %6d ", matriz[i][j]);
 }
 }
 printf("\n\n\n");

 system("pause");
 return 0;
 }
```

por ejemplo si se llega a escribir estos digitos:  **0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5**
la solución debe salir asi:

[image: por ejemplo si se llega a conseguir la solución debe salir asi:]

Agradezco de antemano toda la ayuda que se me puede ofrecer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo la solución a tu problema en el código. La solución no es muy complicada, pero deberías tomarte un tiempo para correr el algoritmo que suma los elementos de la diagonal principal en papel, ya que solo así podrás visualizar mejor como funciona esa parte del código.

Para comprobar la cantidad de números positivos en la matriz solamente debes de hacer la comprobación con una sentencia "if", si el número ingresado es mayor a 0. Si el número es menor que 0, sería un número negativo y por eso no lo incluiría en la cuenta. Pero si el número ingresado fuera "0"  el contador no lo toma en cuenta debido a que el 0 es un número neutro.

```
if(matriz[i][j] > 0){
    cont++;
}
```

Este for permite recorrer el arreglo. Se escribe "i<4" debido a que 4 es el tamño de filas y columnas del arreglo. Al obtener solamente los elementos matriz[i][i] del arreglo, se están obteniendo solamente los elementos de la diagonal principal.

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    sum = sum + matriz[i][i];
}
```

Código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int matriz[4][4], col=4, reng=4, cont=0, sum=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < reng; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) { // Se introducen los digito para hacer la matriz
            printf("ESCRIBE LOS VALORES [%d][%d]==>\t", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
           //Aquí la sentencia if para contar los positivos
            if(matriz[i][j] > 0){
                cont++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\n\t\t MATRIZ:"); // Se imprime la matriz original
    printf("\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < reng; i++) {
        printf("\n\t\t");
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf(" %6d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < reng; i++) {
        printf("\n\t\t");
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf(" %6d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //Aquí el for necesario para sumar los elementos de la diagonal principal
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        sum = sum + matriz[i][i];
    }
    printf("\n\nLa cantidad de numeros positivos es de: %d\n\n", cont);
    printf("\nLa suma de la diagonal principal es de: %d\n\n", sum);
    printf("\n\n\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Si te sirvió de ayuda mi respuesta puedes marcarla con el check como la correcta. No dudes en dejar comentarios si tienes alguna duda.